# How to resize View by dragging from its edges with dynamic pivot?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, scale, gesture

I have a viewGroup and need to resize by dragging it's edges.i have a implemented code successfully to resize view by it's corner.but when i drag from right side if view is rotated then view not stick to it's position when resizing a width . i set a **PivotX** and **PivotY** to **0** to stick a  view but it get problem when view  being rotate so i reset pivot after finish scaling but it make a view jump because it set pivot center in view.

My view is as below.

[image]

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
            return true;
        }
        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

        layBg = (RelativeLayout) getParent();

        LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) layGroup.getLayoutParams();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setPressed(true);

                basex = x_cord;
                basey = y_cord;
                basew = layGroup.getWidth();
                baseh = layGroup.getHeight();
                layGroup.getLocationOnScreen(new int[2]);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                v.setPressed(false);
                layGroup.resetPivot();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int currx = x_cord;
                int curry = y_cord;

                float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(curry - basey, currx - basex));
                if (angle < 0.0f) {
                    angle += 360.0f;
                }

                int changesW = currx - basex;
                int changesH = curry - basey;

                changesW = (int) (Math.sqrt((changesW * changesW) + (changesH * changesH)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle - layGroup.getRotation())));
                int width = (changesW * 2) + basew;

                if (v.getId() == R.id.rightHandle) {
                    if (width > 200) {
                        layGroup.setPivotX(0);
                        layGroup.setPivotY(0);
                        int old_width = layoutParams.width;
                        layoutParams.width += width - old_width;

                        layGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code

Comment: @Rafsanjani sorry ,now updated